# Access Properties of JS Object on Controller

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, javascript-objects

I have created an Ember.JS application where I hang some properties on the `ApplicationController` that need to be accessible form all over the app. One of these properties is queue (a JS object) broken down by server names (JS arrays). In my template I would like to list the items of each array but I'm not really sure how to do it. I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861751/read-object-properties-in-handlebars-template) but I don't really understand the answer.

For my code I have:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentUser: null,
  queuedPlayers: {
    "The Bastion": [],
    "Begeren Colony": [],
    "The Harbinger": [],
    "The Shadowlands": [],
    "Jung Ma": [],
    "The Ebon Hawk": [],
    "Prophecy of the Five": [],
    "Jedi Covenant": []
  }
});
```

The other controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  currentUser: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.currentUser'),
  queuedPlayers: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.queuedPlayers'),
  ...
```

And in the template:

```
{{#each server in servers}}
  <h2>{{server}}</h2>
  {{#each player in queuedPlayers[server]}}
    {{player}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

`servers` is an array of the servers (that matches the properties in `queuedPlayers`) I am passing to the template to use as the content attribute for a select list so the `{{server}}` tag renders fine. However the `queuedPlayers[server]` or `queuedPlayers.get(server)` is obviously not working because that's not how handlebars works but it's what I would like to achieve.

I am primarily a Python dev so JS is somewhat new to me so I'm not familiar with all it's nuances.

Comment: Create a service and inject it into your app's controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a component and pass in the necessary properties in order to accomplish this.

```
{{#each server in servers}}
  <h2>{{server}}</h2>
  {{queued-players collection=queuedPlayers selection=server}}
{{/each}}
```

#### Queued players template

```
{{#each player in players}}
  {{player}}
{{/each}}
```

#### Queued players js

```
players: function(){
  return this.get('collection')[this.get('selection')];
}.property('collection.[]', 'selection')
```

Comment: Took some tweaking, I'm not using an Ember CLI app, but this got the job done. Thanks